# LINQ Query for search criteria

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have 5-6 textboxes and dropdowns, based on the values  I want to fetch the results, 
With OR condition this query works fine however when I use AND for multiple conditions
it wont give me any results due to obvious reason. Now My question is that how can
i change this query to make it working for both AND and OR conditions.

Query

```
Public Sub SerachCriteria()
    Debugger.Break()
    Dim s = New Ex1DataContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url)
    Dim vendors = s.PurchaseOrderWrite
    Dim query = From vendor In vendors.ToList() _
                Where (Not ddsearchorderVendor.SelectedItem.Text = "--Select--" AndAlso vendor.Supplier.Title = ddsearchorderVendor.SelectedItem.Text) _
                Or (Not ddsearchorderStatus.SelectedItem.Text = "--Select--" AndAlso vendor.Status = ddsearchorderStatus.SelectedItem.Text) _
                Or (Not txtSearchOrder.Text Is Nothing AndAlso vendor.Purchaseorderno = txtSearchOrder.Text) _
                Or (Not ddsearchorderdate.Text = "--Select--" AndAlso vendor.Orderdate = ddsearchorderdate.Date) _
                Select vendor.Purchaseorderno
    For Each a In query
        listpurchaseorder.Items.Add(a)
        listpurchaseorder.DataTextField = "Purchaseorderno"
        listpurchaseorder.DataValueField = "ID"
        listpurchaseorder.DataBind()
    Next
    SerachCriteriaPartNo()
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Any one can help in this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For And, you can use a strategy where you concatenate multiple where clauses on demand. See http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Dynamically-extending-LINQ-queryies-without-building-expression-trees. Or is trickier as they typically require your implementation or dynamic expression tree creation. Combining And and Or it is best to consider using the dynamic query library with Linq to SQL.

If you are using EF, I would recommend the ObjectBuilder methods or EntitySQL for EF. See http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/querying-with-linq-to-entities-vs-objectquery-in-ef/ regarding ObjectQuery. Also take a look at the BuilderMethodSamples in http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFQuerySamples. With this, you can just use string concat to build your where clauses. They will still be parameterized and make it more difficult to do SQL injection than dynamic sql would otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for implement dynamic queries.  While LINQ gives you nice type-safe, compile time checking, it can be a bit messy when you need to build queries on the fly.

Have a look at Scott Gu's article on dynamic LINQ queries:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx